# setImmediate() callback not invoked in AWS Lambda using node 8.10

Tags: node.js, lambda

I would like to understand why the callback of setImmediate doesn't get invoked in the following:

```
module.exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  try {
    console.log('calling setImmediate...');
    setImmediate(function () {
      console.log('setImmediate callback invoked!');
      callback(null, 'OK!!!!');
    })
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Failed!');
    console.log(e);
    callback(e);
  }
};
```

The output in CloudWatch is as follows:

```
START RequestId: c2b83f7b-e37a-11e8-ba70-5b99f76ce7ed Version: $LATEST
2018-11-08T17:21:42.922Z    c2b83f7b-e37a-11e8-ba70-5b99f76ce7ed    calling setImmediate...
END RequestId: c2b83f7b-e37a-11e8-ba70-5b99f76ce7ed
REPORT RequestId: c2b83f7b-e37a-11e8-ba70-5b99f76ce7ed  Duration: 35.99 ms  Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 19 MB
```

**Removing the 'async' keyword fixes it**, but I don't understand why.

I've tried to reproduce this behavior outside the lambda environment:

```
async function test(){
  setImmediate(function(){
    console.log('setImmediate callback!')
  })
}

test()
```

But in this example the callback is being invoked.

Anyone could point me in the right direction to understand this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you return a promise, which is what `async` functions do, your lambda ends when the promise resolves. Because your async function doesn’t contain any `await` expressions, the promise it returns resolves immediately. You can’t both take a callback and return a promise.

To `await` on the `setImmediate`, you have to create a promise that resolves when its callback fires. Converting your `callback(e)` into a rejected promise and your `callback(null, 'OK!!!!')` into a resolved promise:

```
module.exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  try {
    console.log('calling setImmediate...');
    return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setImmediate(function () {
        console.log('setImmediate callback invoked!');
        resolve('OK!!!!');
      });
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Failed!');
    console.log(e);
    throw e;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use callback when using async call handlers in Node 8.

Functions declared as async in Node 8 are actually returning a promise. Because you are declaring a callback, your setImmediate function is trying to resolve a 2nd promise, you've essentially set up a race condition where the lambda is ending before running the console log statement inside the function. Either way, you will not actually get your desired response.

Try:

```
module.exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  try {
    console.log('calling setImmediate...');
    var setImmediate = (function () {
      console.log('setImmediate callback invoked!');
      return('OK!!!!');
    });
    return setImmediate();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Failed!');
    console.log(e);
    return(e);
  }
};
```

Your code will work if you remove the async declaration, because the old callback syntax is still supported.